# Hyper-V excessive Memory Demand with static memory

Tags: debian, networking, memory, memory-leaks, hyper-v

I have Gen 2 VM with Debian 10.5 in a Hyper-V(2019) host. Currently its running a web app which does not use much memory (the system monitor shows its using 2GB out of 8GB), but the memory demand frequently exceeds the assigned one.

Startup memory: 8196 MB
Dynamic memory: Disabled
Assigned memory: 8196 MB
Memory demand: 10818 MB

In addition the web app page often gets connection not found when I ping the server I get frequent 'Request time out'.

1. Why is the memory demand so high? What could create this effect?
2. Is the connection loss affected by the memory demand?
3. What should I look for to pinpoint the connection problem?

PS: Im fairly new to this so if there is more info I should provide please let me know.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and like to ask whether you find a solution? Reading your post, I stuck on this: on headline you talk about static memory, where in your further description you mentioned using dynamic memory?

Comment: @MMAX indeed I tried both. Eventually we decided to give it excess memory so that it will at least take longer for it to reach peak. Additionally I made some code optimizations that also helped. So basically, no, I didnt find a solution. Just a patchwork to make it work for longer.